# .NET SignalR client not able to subscribe to server events

Tags: .net, signalr.client

I am trying to use SignalR in a .NET client. I am able to connect successfully but nothing happens when I try to subscribe to the events. I am not able to receive the messages sent from the server. I am very new to this area, so I am not sure whether I am missing something or something is wrong in my code.

```
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(<url>);

        // Hub name from dev code
        var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("pidHub");

        // Subscribing to all the events
        proxy.On("SendTransactionUpdate", () => Logger.LogInformation("SendTransactionUpdate ************************"));
        proxy.On("SendMessage", () => Logger.LogInformation("SendMessage ************************"));
        proxy.On("UpdateStatus", () => Logger.LogInformation("UpdateStatus ************************"));
        proxy.On("TransactionUpdate", () => Logger.LogInformation("TransactionUpdate ************************"));


        // This block executes fine
        hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("There was an error opening the connection: {0}" + task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Connected. *********");
            }
        }).Wait();

        // Call Provision GUID API and returns a valid GUID
        <call API>

        // Downloads EXE on machine
        <download EXE code>

        // Run EXE with -d option
        // EXE uploads results back to the server and server returns some messages through SignalR
        // I want to capture these messages
        <execute EXE on machine>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You might want to subscribe to the event on the task continuation when the task is not faulted.
2. If you have managed to connect to the server you might want to use fiddler to trace server messages.
3. Make sure your event handlers contains parameters if there are any, for the argument sent from the server. Your application may receive the messages but handle them wrong.